# In the figure below, $\overline{EF}$ is a diameter of the circle. What is the measure of $\angle ABC$, in degrees?

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, angle

In the figure below, $\overline{EF}$ is a diameter of the circle. What is the measure of $\angle ABC$, in degrees?

[image: Diagram]

Would listing angles help me?  If so, how?

Comment: Hint: [secant angle](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/SecantAngle.shtml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arc $\;\overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{AC\,} = 180^\circ - \;\overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{CF\,} - \;\overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{AE\,} = 180^\circ - 80^\circ - 35^\circ = 65^\circ$.

Then by the interior secant angle formula: $
\widehat{ABC} = \frac{1}{2}(\;\overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{AC\,} + \;\overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{EF\,}) = \frac{1}{2}(65^\circ + 180^\circ) = 
122.5^\circ$.

( The above assumes that the given values refer to angles $\widehat{COF} = 80^\circ$ and $\widehat{AOE} = 35^\circ$. )

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\widehat{CEF}=40^\circ,\qquad \widehat{AFE}=35^\circ $$
hence
$$\widehat{ABC}=\widehat{EBF}=180^\circ-(40^\circ+35^\circ) = \color{red}{105^\circ}.$$
( I am guessing that the depicted $80^\circ$ and $35^\circ$ angles are $\widehat{COF}$ and $\widehat{AFE}$ ).

Comment: Looks to me more like the $35^\circ$ angle is $\widehat{AOE}$ if the drawing is anywhere close to scale.

Comment: @dxiv: I made such assumptions because the depicted $\widehat{AOE}$ angle looks way bigger than $35^\circ$, but in any case the above solution can be easily adapted to the actual situation.

Answer (score 1):

$\angle ABC=180^\circ -(\angle CEF +\angle AFE)=180^\circ-(40^\circ +17.5^\circ)=122.5^\circ$

Comment: FWIW proof looks good, but after this latest edit it became identical to the one posted earlier by @JackD'Aurizio (except for the different interpretation of which one is the $35^\circ$ angle).